# Cómo ejecutar el programa hasta que encuentre estos carácteres en la entrada?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo que hacer un programa que, mientras no encuentre un arroba y un punto no deje de hacer la pregunta para entrar

Al encontrar un el arroba se termina el programa y no "busca" el punto ni llega a la condición de que si "encuentra el punto y el arroba" saque el mensaje de "bienvenido al sistema"

Este es mi código: Si alguien me explica también que hice mal, se los agradecería muchísimo.

```java
package repaso;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Buscararrobaypunto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean arroba=false;
        boolean punto=false;
        String correo;
        
        
        while(arroba==false && punto==false) {
            correo=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba su cuenta de correo");
            
            for(int i=0; i<correo.length(); i++) {
                if(correo.charAt(i)=='@') {
                    arroba=true;
                }
                if(correo.charAt(i)=='.') {
                    punto=true;
                }
            }
        }
        
                 if(arroba==true && punto==true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correo Correcto", "Bienvenido al Sistema", 2);
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: ỳ cual es el error? o debemos de adivinar?

Comment: Que al encontrar un el arroba se termina el programa y no "busca" el punto ni llega a la condición de que si "encuentra el punto y el arroba" saque el mensaje de "bienvenido al sistema"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te falla es la lógica.

Si lo que quieres es seguir pidiendo el correo mientras la entrada del usuario no contenga una arroba y un punto, la condición del `while` debe ser OR y no AND, ya que si NO se ha encontrado la arroba o NO se ha encontrado el punto debes continuar. Si pones un AND lo que dices es que debe continuar solo cuando no se han concontrado ninguno, pero como al menos encuenta uno de los dos termina su ejecución.

Quedaría así:

```
while(arroba==false || punto==false)
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! eso era lo que necesitaba y más con tu explicación para comprender el uso de los carácteres. Nuevamente, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que dices, tu código no debe de funcionar.

Yo utilizaría una expresión regular para ver si la variable "correo" contiene un @ y al menos un punto. Entiendo que lo que pretendes encontrar es un correo electrónico. Yo haría algo así:

```
// Creas la expresión regular a través de Pattern
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)");

// Aplicas el patron a correo
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(correo);

// Utilizas el metodo find() para encontrar la siguiente ocurrencia. Si el contenido de la variable "correo" cumple el patrón, entonces entra en el while, sino no.
while (matcher.find()) {
    // Aquí podrías setear tus variables a true, o con una sola te debería llegar.
}
```

La expresión regular del patrón que he puesto de ejemplo es probable que no sea el mejor a utilizar. Puedes probar a crear otra expresión en https://regex101.com/

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, pero como apenas estamos en bucles... se supone que la debemos hacer así. Perdona mi ignorancia, pero aún no llegamos a las expresiones que mencionas :(... pero estudiaré tu enlace.

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona simplemente por la condición que evaluá que ambos sean `true` pero si solo uno es `true` entonces el bucle para ya que no se cumple la condición. El operador a utilizar debería ser el **or** (`||`). Pero al modificar eso verás el comportamiento real de tu programa. Si en la primera iteración colocas un punto, por ejemplo `hola.` entonces se vuelve a repetir el ciclo y si esta vez ingresa el arroba, por ejemplo `hol@` entonces el programa finaliza. Esto por que las variables `arroba` y `punto` no son reseteadas en la nueva ejecución del ciclo. Lo recomendable sería establecer el valor dentro del ciclo.

```java
public class Buscararrobaypunto {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean punto;
        boolean arroba;
        String correo;
        
        while(!punto || !arroba){
                arroba=false;
                punto=false;
                //pones tu JOption
                Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
                System.out.println("Enter username");
                correo = myObj.nextLine();
                
            for(int i=0; i<correo.length(); i++) {
                if(correo.charAt(i)=='@') {
                    arroba=true;
                }
                if(correo.charAt(i)=='.') {
                    punto=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(arroba && punto){
           // lo cambias por tu JOption
          System.out.println("yep");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias infinitas! Excelente también tu respuesta, lo haré enseguida para acabarla de comprender. :) Disculpa, estoy también aprendiendo a usar esta gran página. Fue mi primera vez... jajajaja

Comment: un placer ayudar y bienvenido al sitio, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y que leas [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ya que tienes 3 respuestas